# Tic Tac Toe Server/Clients issue telling other client they lost after game ends

Tags: java

So my group and I for class have to modify pre-existing code to add for a win/loss/draw condition. We have it setup so when the client wins, the client that won displays and the server displays. We cannot figure out how to tell the server to tell the other client that they lost. Been working on this issue for two weeks now.

server connections

```
 public void execute()
{
  // wait for each client to connect
  for ( int i = 0; i < players.length; i++ ) 
  {
     try // wait for connection, create Player, start runnable
     {
        players[ i ] = new Player( server.accept(), i );
        runGame.execute( players[ i ] ); // execute player runnable
     } // end try
     catch ( IOException ioException ) 
     {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
        System.exit( 1 );
     } // end catch
  } // end for

  gameLock.lock(); // lock game to signal player X's thread
public boolean validateAndMove( int location, int player )
{
  // while not current player, must wait for turn
  while ( player != currentPlayer ) 
  {
     gameLock.lock(); // lock game to wait for other player to go

     try 
     {
        otherPlayerTurn.await(); // wait for player's turn
     } // end try
     catch ( InterruptedException exception )
     {
        exception.printStackTrace();
     } // end catch
     finally
     {
        gameLock.unlock(); // unlock game after waiting
     } // end finally
  } // end while
```

server run

```
public void run()
  {
     // send client its mark (X or O), process messages from client
     try 
     {
        displayMessage( "Player " + mark + " connected\n" );
        output.format( "%s\n", mark ); // send player's mark
        output.flush(); // flush output

        // if player X, wait for another player to arrive
        if ( playerNumber == PLAYER_X ) 
        {
           output.format( "%s\n%s", "Player X connected",
              "Waiting for another player\n" );
           output.flush(); // flush output

           gameLock.lock(); // lock game to  wait for second player

           try 
           {
              while( suspended )
              {
                 otherPlayerConnected.await(); // wait for player O
              } // end while
           } // end try 
           catch ( InterruptedException exception ) 
           {
              exception.printStackTrace();
           } // end catch
           finally
           {
              gameLock.unlock(); // unlock game after second player
           } // end finally

           // send message that other player connected
           output.format( "Other player connected. Your move.\n" );
           output.flush(); // flush output

        } // end if
        else
        {
           output.format( "Player O connected, please wait\n" );
           output.flush(); // flush output
        } // end else

        // while game not over
        while ( !isGameOver() ) 
        {               
           int location = 0; // initialize move location

           if ( input.hasNext() )
              location = input.nextInt(); // get move location

           // check for valid move
           if ( validateAndMove( location, playerNumber ) ) 
           {    
                displayMessage( "\nlocation: " + location );
                output.format( "Valid move.\n" ); // notify client                  

                ticTacBoard[location] = markLocation(location);
                   if(checkForXWin())
                   {                                                                                 
                       output.format( "Player X Has Won!\n"  );                           
                       displayMessage( "\nPlayer X Has Won!" );
                   }
                   else if(checkForOWin())
                   {
                       output.format( "Player O Has Won!\n"  );                           
                       displayMessage( "\nPlayer O Has Won!" );
                   }
                   else if(checkForDraw())
                   {
                       output.format( "We have a Draw!\n"  );                           
                       displayMessage( "We have a Draw!\n");
                       gameLock.lock();
                   }
               output.flush();
           } // end if
           else // move was invalid
           {
              output.format( "Invalid move, try again\n" );
              output.flush(); // flush output
           } // end else
```

client connection

```
public void startClient()
{
  try // connect to server and get streams
  {
     // make connection to server
     connection = new Socket(
        InetAddress.getByName( ticTacToeHost ), 12345 );

     // get streams for input and output
     input = new Scanner( connection.getInputStream() );
     output = new Formatter( connection.getOutputStream() );
  } // end try
  catch ( IOException ioException )
  {
     ioException.printStackTrace();
  } // end catch

  // create and start worker thread for this client
  ExecutorService worker = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 1 );
  worker.execute( this ); // execute client
} // end method startClient
```

client read/write

```
private void processMessage( String message )
{       
  // valid move occurred
  if ( message.equals( "Valid move." ) )
  {
     displayMessage( "Valid move, please wait.\n" );
     setMark( currentSquare, myMark ); // set mark in square
  } // end if
  else if ( message.equals( "Invalid move, try again" ) )
  {
     displayMessage( message + "\n" ); // display invalid move
     myTurn = true; // still this client's turn
  } // end else if
  else if ( message.equals( "Opponent moved" ) )
  {
     int location = input.nextInt(); // get move location
     input.nextLine();  //skip next line
     int row = location / 3; // calculate row
     int column = location % 3; // calculate column
     setMark(  board[ row ][ column ],
        ( myMark.equals( X_MARK ) ? O_MARK : X_MARK ) ); // mark move
     displayMessage( "Opponent moved. Your turn.\n" );
     myTurn = true; // now this client's turn  

  } // end else if

  else
     displayMessage( message + "\n" ); // display the message

 }
```

Comment: You need to isolate a more concrete problem and provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The above code is most likely not minimal.

Comment: Parts of the code look like they don't compile, so the question will likely attract downvotes.